# expression '<expression>' cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: oracle, plsql

In this procedure I'm getting error on the COALESCE functions:

> [Error] PLS-00363 (1091: 30): PLS-00363: expression '' cannot be used as an assignment target.

Which parameters should I declare as out or in out?...I tried o_max_bet, o_min_bet, o_max_win but error is the same...

Following is whole procedure:

```
   PROCEDURE open_session_3w (
      i_player_id              NUMBER,
      old_session_id           NUMBER,
      i_ip_address             VARCHAR2,
      i_machine_number         VARCHAR2,
      o_last_bet         OUT   NUMBER,
      o_min_bet         in out   NUMBER,
      o_max_bet          in out  NUMBER,
      o_max_win         in out  NUMBER,
      o_credits          OUT   NUMBER,
      o_session_id       OUT   NUMBER,
      o_state            OUT   VARCHAR2
   )
   IS
      o_percentage       NUMBER;   
      o_pot              NUMBER;                           
      pom                weak_cur;
      p_active_session   NUMBER;
      p_parent           number;
      v_max_win           number;
      v_min_bet           number;
      v_max_bet           number;
   BEGIN
     select parent_id into p_parent from casino_users where party_id = i_player_id;
      check_pl_sess_3w (i_player_id, old_session_id);
      o_session_id :=

     player.open_new_session (i_player_id, i_ip_address,i_machine_number,'GAME SESSION');

 select MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MAX_WIN' THEN VALUE END ),
           MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MAX_BET' THEN VALUE END ),
           MAX( CASE WHEN gp.name = 'MIN_BET' THEN VALUE END )
    INTO v_max_win,v_max_bet,v_min_bet
          FROM   game_definition_aff gda,
         GAME_PARAMETAR gp,
         game_aff ga,
         game_name gn    
         WHERE   i_player_id = ga.aff_id 
          AND   ga.id = gda.game_aff_id
          AND   gp.id = gda.game_parametar_id
          AND   15 = ga.game_name_id
          AND   gn.game_name_id = ga.game_name_id
          and gp.name in ( 'MIN_BET','MAX_BET','MAX_WIN') ;

      player.get_percentage (i_player_id,
                             o_session_id,
                             royal_tri_win,
                             o_percentage,
                             COALESCE(v_min_bet,o_min_bet),
                             COALESCE(v_max_bet,o_max_bet),
                             COALESCE(v_max_win,o_max_win),
                             o_pot
                            );
    .
    .
    .

end open_session_3w ;   


PROCEDURE get_percentage (i_player_id NUMBER, i_session_id NUMBER, i_game_id NUMBER, o_percentage OUT NUMBER, o_min_bet OUT NUMBER, o_max_bet OUT NUMBER, o_max_win OUT NUMBER, o_pot OUT NUMBER)
```

Comment: What is the full error stack and which code do the line numbers in the error relate to? And what is the spec for `player.get_percentage` - are the arguments that you're passing via the coalesce calls declared as `in` or `[in] out`? I imagine they are the latter, which would explain the error.

Comment: PROCEDURE get_percentage (i_player_id        NUMBER,
                             i_session_id       NUMBER,
                             i_game_id          NUMBER,
                             o_percentage   OUT NUMBER,
                             o_min_bet      OUT NUMBER,
                             o_max_bet      OUT NUMBER,
                             o_max_win      OUT NUMBER,
                             o_pot          OUT NUMBER)
full stack error is [Error] PLS-00363 (1091: 30): PLS-00363: expression '' cannot be used as an assignment target. * 3 for every coalesce function

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, particularly code. But yes, the arguments are `OUT`, so that procedure will try to set them, and you have to pass in a variable for it to set. It isn't clear what you are actually trying to achieve with your coalesce though, or what you will do with the values the procedure sets.

Comment: What I want is from the select where I insert into v_max_win,v_max_bet,v_min_bet to pass into get_percentage but if v_max_win,v_max_bet,v_min_bet are null then use o_min_bet,o_max_bet,o_max_win as parameters

Comment: But `get_percentage` has `OUT` arguments, so it cannot be passed anything. Is that procedure actually trying to set those arguments; or is it trying to do a calculation based on them; or both? You're showing us a small part of the overall functionality you're working on, and there isn't enough to suggest what you should do...